# avoid SQL injections with a parameter parser

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I have a Stored procedure that has many parameters (all varchar), some parameters are used in where clause and others are used as table names.  I have read many articles suggesting to use quotename for table names, escape single quotes, % and _ and white listing or black listing words or characters.

In my case, the quotename won't work as adding the [] breaks my procedure, since I use sys.tables where name = @tablename to validate get the columns from sys.columns.

So I have decided to create a generic function to validate the parameters to avoid SQL injections... this simple function takes an @input parameter and returns a modified version of the @input variable (if unwanted characters are found). this function uses the replace command when the following characters (or words)  are found:

' -- /* */ % ; + [ UNION DROP CREATE INSERT SELECT UPDATE UNION

The function that I have build looks like this:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[AntiSQLInjection] (@input varchar(8000))
Returns varchar(8000)
As
Begin

Return 
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
                                                    replace(
                                                        replace(
                                                            replace(
                                                                replace(@input,
                                                                '''',''''''),
                                                            'UNION',''),
                                                        '--',''),
                                                    '/*',''),
                                                '*/',''),
                                            'DROP ',''),
                                        'ALTER ',''),
                                    'CREATE ',''),
                                '%','[%]'),
                            '[','[[]'),
                        ';',''),
                    '+',''),
                'SELECT ',''),
            'UPDATE ',''),
        'INSERT ',''),
    'DELETE ','')

End
```

I can't get rid of the dynamic SQL... My question is "Does this function cover all different angles to avoid SQL injections?"

here are some examples of code using the parameters, I would parse the parameters with the AntiSQLInjection function:

```
SET @SQLStr = ' SELECT c.name, CASE WHEN y.name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Set_Columns 
                INTO TMP_Col
                FROM sys.tables t 
                JOIN sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id 
                JOIN (SELECT c.name 
                        FROM sys.tables t 
                        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                        WHERE t.name = ''' + @tar_local + ''') x ON x.name = c.name
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.name 
                        FROM sys.tables t 
                        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                        WHERE t.name = ''' + @tar_local + ''') y ON y.name = c.name and y.name in (''' + CASE WHEN @set_local IS NULL THEN 'No Set Parameter' ELSE REPLACE(@set_local,';',''',''') END + ''')
                WHERE t.name = ''TMP_9999999'''
EXEC (@SQLStr)
```

;

```
SET @SQLStr = 'INSERT INTO TMP_PK_TAB_9999999 (TABLE_QUALIFIER, TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,KEY_SEQ, PK_NAME)
                    EXEC sp_pkeys ''' + @tar_local + ''''
EXEC (@SQLStr)
```

; and more complicated -> params are @tar_local, @src_local, @key_local... the other variables are built strings within the SP which I'm not worried about.

```
SET @SQLStr = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tar_local + '(' + @ColumnsStr + ') SELECT S.' + REPLACE(@ColumnsStr,',',',S.') + ' FROM (' + @src_local + ') S LEFT JOIN ' + @tar_local + ' T ON T.' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@key_local,' ',''),'=:','= S.'),'AND',' AND T.') + 
                                    ' WHERE T.' + SUBSTRING(@ColumnsStr,PATINDEX('%F%',@ColumnsStr), CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%,%',@ColumnsStr) = 0 THEN LEN(@ColumnsStr)-PATINDEX('%F%',@ColumnsStr) ELSE PATINDEX('%,%',@ColumnsStr) - PATINDEX('%F%',@ColumnsStr) END) + ' IS NULL'
                    EXEC(@SQLStr)
```

I know this isn't the cleanest way,  if you have any other ideas please feel free  to share.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to clean the input at the SQL Server level? And also, why are you trying to *clean* the input? If the input contains `INSERT` and that should never be part of a valid input, why are you just removing that text rather than *rejecting* the input and refusing to run any code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right.  I'm at the point that I want to breakdown the type of data and split into different functions that will return valid or not. and then react based on the result of the different functions.  For example, I will have a function that will validate when I'm expecting a table name and another function that will validate when I'm expecting a field or a data value.